# Remove url from end user in ui routing

Tags: angularjs

I am building angular single page application with ui-routing. I need to hide the url after the domain from end user.It shuld not affect any other feature like accessing url or anything, but just want to hide the state changes from end user. Which is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with  ui-router library by  creating the URL-less states and navigate to them ,like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state("home", {
        url: "",
        template: "<a ui-sref='next'>Next page</a>"
      })
      .state("next", {
        template: "<a ui-sref='home'>Back</a>"
      });
  });
```

Comment: First I like to thanks for your response. i think it may not be possible to avoid url as blank, since i have to access state params from url in many stages for api calls and all.i dont't have to leave my url as blank but just want to hide it.

Comment: so you want passing data between two states without exposing the data in the url,, right...?